# Appropriate HTML markup to display currently logged in user and datetime information

Tags: html

I want to display the name of the user currently logged in and the date.

At the moment I've put them together in one line within a paragraph tag element:

```
<div id="userinfo">
    <p>#Title# #FirstName# #Surname# #DateFormat(GetDate(), "dd/mm/yyy")#</p>
</div>
```

Its not exactly a paragraph of text, so I'm thinking semantically its invalid HTML5.

Could anyone please suggest what element would be best to contain this type of content thats HTML valid?

Comment: How about `<section id="user">`?

Comment: Its within its own div... I was referring more to actual user information and time.

Comment: @volumeone Why would you include the date as part of the user-box? As far as I'm concerned, the date should be outside, and the date would be as useful to a visitor as it is to a logged-in user.

Comment: @Goodwine the entire div is only available to a logged-in user. There is nothing shown if someone is not logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use something like this:

```
<section id="userinfo">
    <h1>#Title# #FirstName# #Surname</h1>
    <time datetime="Thu, 18 Jul 2013 02:23:45 +0000">#DateFormat(GetDate(), "dd/mm/yyy")</time>
</section>
```

Time tag is the appropriate choice, and you must use the format "Thu, 18 Jul 2013 02:23:45 +0000" inside.